# Readable file only by PHP

Tags: php, chmod

I have another question:

when i write `localhost/folder/file.txt` into browser, it opens and show the content of file.txt.

But I want make this file readable only by PHP, not by browser.

I tried everything with `chmod` but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: The most reliable way is putting it outside the web root.

Comment: I know this question is old, but for anyone who is interested: If it's only a small amount of data you want to store, then I recommend using a PHP encrypt/decrypt function - so people can only access the data with the correct key (which is stored in the PHP file). Otherwise, like others have suggested, use a database. I like using MySQL. Databases are only accessible with the correct username + password. You could also encrypt the data inside your database, just to add that extra layer of security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refuse access to the `.txt` extension.

`.htaccess`

```
# prevent viewing of a specific file
<Files file.txt>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# multiple file types
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|txt)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Putting it outside the web root is still more solid, - `AllowOverride` in the server config could change and render this moot

Comment: I'm saying if `AllowOverride` changes in the central server config, this would leave the file unprotected. That shouldn't happen but it could. (Not my downvote though, sometimes this is the only way)

Comment: can i refuse access to a folder?

Comment: @MarekSchubert Access/Listing is refused mostly by the provider, by adding `Options All -Indexes` you force that...

Answer (score 5):

Write to a file *outside* the web root, then the web server won't make it available to clients. (There is no requirement for a file to be under the document root for PHP to read it).

Other options include:

- Using your webserver's auth/authz systems to secure the file (not recommended for this problem as it is more likely that a configuration error will break the security then it is that the file will be placed in the wrong place)
- Using a database instead

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text file into a mySQL database as BLOB or TEXT. So it becomes impossible to read by browser, only by query (through php).

Comment: That's a very original suggestion, but there are arguably easier ways. :)

Comment: And better ways, for the purpose you want, you don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution :

```
$s=file_get_contents('test.txt');
```

If the file has some code to execute, you can `eval` it.

```
eval(file_get_contents('test.txt'));
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried chmod it to 660 ?

I just tried it using my web server, it is not available.

Comment: Since the PHP script is usually running as the same user as the webserver, if you set the permissions so the server can't read it, then the PHP script won't be able to read it either.

Comment: A "Have you tried...?"-answer without explaining why it would work, could cause more harm than benefit. If you have a suggestion, please argue why it would work rather than leaving readers confused (in this particular case it won't work as @Quentin explains).